# How do I read from severals files in C?

Tags: c, text-files

I am working on a program which have to read from txt files.
I know that there's a function called `fopen("myfile.txt","rt")`, but what if I have 10 files? Do i need to call the function 10 times (a call for every file)?

Comment: The "t" in your example is an extension that not all C implementations have. The Standard defines the mode "r" as "open the file for reading and perform text-translation as needed (text mode)"; and it defines the mode "rb" as "open the file for reading and do not perform any translation (binary mode)"

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But if you perform the same routines on each of those functions, abstract that behaviour into a function that accepts the name of a file. Now call that function 10 times, once with each file name.

```
void read_from_text_file(char const *filepath);

read_from_text_file("myfile.txt");
read_from_text_file("myfile2.txt");
...
```

This is a core concept in computer science. Buzzwords include "abstraction", "routine", "reusability", etc.

Comment: thank you all! this is my program: GasStationManager.exe. the file: simulationfile contains the actions that we need to perform on the files: station1 station2 station3 station4.... how can we pass the arguments to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One function call per file is needed.